# How to determine gender count in a data grouped with groupby in python programming language?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, data-science, filtering

In the data set of a market, each data belongs to a product group. I want to group this data group by fische number and find the total number of male and female customers.
The data set is as in the picture. [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKZgm.png) The number of unique fischeno is 141783. Therefore, the total number of customers should be 141783.

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mFZB.png)

Comment: `total number of male and female characters` as in? Total males and females in each unique fische number?

Comment: I added an example to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna count the total number of each gender column, you may try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
df = df.groupby('ficheno').first()
male_count = df[df.gender == 'm'].gender.count()
female_count = df[df.gender == 'f'].gender.count()
```

This will result in male = 2, female = 3 according to your sample dataset.

Comment: The number of unique ficheno in this dataset is equal to the total number of people in the dataset. in the example there are 5 different people since there are 5 different ficheno: 3 female 2 male

Comment: @ErenDemir you can check my updated answer.